# How to enable openLDAP to use LDAP over SSL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openldap

I already have the conventional openLDAP setup on my ubuntu machine.
Can anyone help me in providing details,as to enable the already installed ldap to ldaps?
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SecuringOpenLDAPConnections wiki page on Ubuntu official site:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecuringOpenLDAPConnections

Comment: Thanks @Cyril Dangerville  ,I did check the above link ,but did not get it working ,instead this link helped me https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html.en

Comment: Indeed, your link is the right one if you are using v18.04 since it is the official documentation. **I can edit my answer or do you prefer to answer your own post (and accept your answer)?** It is for other people to quicky find the proper answer instead of checking the comments